# No option to create account on Ubuntu install

Tags: virtualbox

Installing Ubuntu 22.04 in VirtualBox and I'm not being prompted to set up a sudo account. I see the prompt to try or install, and once I select that it just installs the OS with no other options being available during that process, i.e. language or region. Then it comes up with the login screen and I can only log in as vboxuser. I've tried to reinstall 3 times. Shouldn't there be a prompt to set up an account for the box and to be able to give it root privileges?

Comment: Where are you getting your installation media from? Maybe it's been customised before-hand

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: "able to give it (the account) `root` privileges" is easy: add the userid to the `sudo` group in `/etc/groups`, or `sudo adduser the_userid sudo`. Do; `getent group sudo` to see if any userid is in group `sudo` already, or `grep sudo /etc/groups` to only check locally. After you add the userid to the `sudo` group, the userid Will have to logout/login to use `sudo`. Read `man sudo sudoers`.

Comment: I appreciate the help and I will do that, I'm still just confused why I'm not being prompted for any of that? I thought that I must be doing some thing wrong, but theres not a lot for me to screw up here.